# applying class to element found with test

Tags: class, xslt

I'm still new to working with XSLT

How do I apply a class to an element found with an xsl:if

XML:

```
<ColumnBody><h3>Some Text</h3></ColumnBody>
```

The output that I want:

```
<h3 class="box-list-link">Some Text </h3>
```

I have something that does this:

```
<xsl:for-each select ="./ColumnBody" >
     <xsl:call-template name="RichText"></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template name="RichText">
      <p>
            <xsl:copy-of select="./node()" />
      </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This question would be a lot clearer if we could see the input XML and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h3">
    <h3 class="box-list-link">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </h3>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```